# SocketError: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to run a docker container inside a rails application, however I keep receiving the following error:-

`container = Docker::Container.create({'Image' => 'mitc/judge'})`

> Excon::Errors::SocketError: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /var/run/docker.sock (Errno::ENOENT)`

The environment variables are set

`bash-3.2$ env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/ayushlodha/.docker/machine/machines/dev`

The container is able to run hello world

`bash-3.2$ docker run mitc/judge /bin/echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
bash-3.2$ docker run -it mitc/judge
judge@4a19cdd8b328:/tmp/judge$`

I am using Mac and Kitematic. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Kitematic, the socket file hasn't been created yet. You nee to create it manually. You can use the command:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

and then run your ruby application.

Refer:

https://github.com/swipely/docker-api

https://github.com/kitematic/kitematic/issues/517